# Option to prevent outer yank (ya') from yanking leading whitespace?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, whitespace

If i have something like

```
foo(
  'parameter'
)
```

and I press `ya'` with the cursor somewhere inside the `parameter` string then the indentation space gets yanked too and I end up with   `'parameter'` in my `*` register.

Is there some option or some other command which prevents that white space from being copied? That would be, ending with `'parameter'` in the `*` register?

To give another example, if I had

```
const a = 'some string'
```

I would want to end up with `'some string'` and not  `'some string'`.

Ideally, I would want to avoid that white space when I do `da'`, too.

Comment: why not simply `di'`?

Comment: An alternative command that will get the word and the single quotes but not any leading/trailing whitespace is `yaW`. For your two-word example, `y2aW` (cursor must be on first word).

Comment: @Mass I want to capture the quotes too. Thanks @B Layer, that does the trick

Comment: @ffigari FYI only one `@` name gets notified, unfortunately. That's why it took me so long...didn't see this until Quasimodo hit me up. (The rules on notifications are kinda convoluted:  [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) )  Cheers.

Comment: Oh got it @BLayer, I doubted whether that @ would work. What's Quasimodo btw?

Comment: @ffigari A user. They deleted the comment that notified me. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no option or variation of a command that uses `'`. But we can use a different text object that will select what you want, i.e. [`aW`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#aW) ...

```
yaW
```

This will yank `parameter` and the single quotes but not any leading or trailing white space.

As for your two-word example, if you put the cursor on the first word `some` then you can just add a count to the above command and you'll yank `'some string'`, also without leading/trailing white space...

```
y2aW
```